# How to serve a Vue.js webpack project from a subdirectory

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I've searched for hours for a solution and it didn't come up.
I have a project based on Vue.js 2 + webpack (using webpack template) as shown below:

[image: Directories structure of the project]

Well, there are two folders for assets: `src/assets/` and `static`.
I've read about the difference of them and discovered that the files that are in `src/assets/` will be loaded by webpack as modules and the ones sotred in `static/` will be loaded as they are (please correct me if I'm wrong or complement the information that I misunderstood). But even with this information, I couldn't find a way to get what I need.

Here's the issue:

I want to host the dist version of the project in a subdirectory like `mydomain.com/subdirectory` but, when I upload the code there the files are loaded directly from `mydomain.com/static/` when they should be loaded from `mydomain.com/subdirectory/static/`.

I tried changing `assetsSubDirectory` and `assetsPublicPath` in the `build` attribute settings in the `config/index.js` file (shown below) in several ways but I couldn't get what I really need. Sometimes the images and css files get loaded from the right place but the JS files generated by webpack don't or the other way around.

```
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
  dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 8080,
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},
    // CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are "buggy"
    // with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
    // (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
    // In our experience, they generally work as expected,
    // just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you are using vue-cli

set build attribute like this in config/index.js:

```
 assetsSubDirectory: 'subdirectory/static/',
 assetsPublicPath: '/',
```

then run

```
npm run build
```

you will get a dist folder like this:

```
.
├── index.html
└── subdirectory
    └── static
        ├── css
        │   ├── app.201d8caff7556318f5a3e08a46cb487d.css
        │   └── app.201d8caff7556318f5a3e08a46cb487d.css.map
        └── js
            ├── app.be4eeaeed988e54df219.js
            ├── app.be4eeaeed988e54df219.js.map
            ├── manifest.116a87efb9d4edc91c95.js
            ├── manifest.116a87efb9d4edc91c95.js.map
            ├── vendor.8659787d0b39fda686fd.js
            └── vendor.8659787d0b39fda686fd.js.map
```

Comment: I tried this approach but, for example, in my `index.html` file, my assets are still beeing loaded from  `/static/` like `<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` or `<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` and, in my Vue components files (placed all in the same folder)  stays like `<img src="/static/images/barbell-dark-icon.png" alt="barbell-icon" class="img-responsive">`. So if I change this setting I have to change all of my assets references in the app. I'd like to have a config for dev and another for production. =/

Comment: @vcpablo files in static static/ are not processed by webpack, so root-relative urls like /staic/a.png are not processed. you can use a method to return different url for build and dev environment. like this:      

  ` getUrl: function(url) {
            if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
                return "/subdirectory" + url;
            }
            else {
                return url;
            }
        } 
`


then use it in img: 


` <img :src="getUrl('/static/images/a.jpg')" alt="">`

Comment: Do you mean by creating a global method for all of my Vue instance in order to generate this URL dynamically? This seems like a hack. Is this really it? I'm frustrated I haven't found anything "right" and simple.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @vcpablo did you end up finding a solution to this problem? I've spent hours on this

Answer (score 0):

change config/index.js like this, make reference relative to current dir

```
// Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: './static',
    assetsPublicPath: './',
```